# Program crashing when concatenating file paths with / using boost::filesystem on Mac

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, boost, filesystems

When I concatenate file paths with operator/ using Boost's Filesystem Path class, my program crashes when it executes that line of code and throws an EXC_BAD_ACCESS exception on OS X with Xcode 4.6.3.

```
boost::filesystem::path macintoshHD("Macintosh HD");
boost::filesystem::path library("Library");

library = macintoshHD / library; // EXC_BAD_ACCESS
```

The same happens when I try to concatenate a path with string constants or std::strings.

```
boost::filesystem::path cwd(boost::filesystem::current_path());

boost::filesystem::path resources = cwd / "Resources"; // EXC_BAD_ACCESS
```

The problem appears to be in Boost/Filesystem/Path itself. What might be the cause of this, and how could I fix it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Changing my compiler from Apple LLVM 4.2 to LLVM GCC 4.2 fixed the bug.

Apparently Apple's compiler stores string constants in char[1] buffers. Boost treats char[1]'s as empty paths and disregards them assuming that a char[1] is only large enough to hold the terminal null character.

This website helped me understand what was happening:
http://boost.2283326.n4.nabble.com/boost-filesystem-path-operator-is-broken-for-char-1-in-1-48-td4574639.html

Comment: You [can answer your own question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) (time restrictions apply). In fact, you should answer your question, to help future visitors.

Comment: I know, but since my reputation is so low (I just joined), I have to wait another 6 hours before I can answer my own question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing my compiler from **Apple LLVM 4.2** to **LLVM GCC 4.2** fixed the bug.

Apparently Apple's compiler stores string constants in char[1] buffers. Boost treats char[1]'s as empty paths and disregards them assuming that a char[1] is only large enough to hold the terminal null character.

This website helped me understand what was happening:
http://boost.2283326.n4.nabble.com/boost-filesystem-path-operator-is-broken-for-char-1-in-1-48-td4574639.html